# Registry - Pass parameter to default browser

Tags: windows-7, browser, windows-registry

We have a default Firefox shortcut which gets started as `[...]\Firefox.exe -profile [path-to-profile]`

When a user clicks a link (e.g. in Outlook) firefox opens but without the `-profile` addition.

After searching around a bit and looking at the registry with regshot i found, that when setting firefox to default browser changes a few registry settings like `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-[...]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.htm\UserChoice` , `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxHTML` and so on...

Is it possible (by setting a registry key, etc) to make the "default browser"-firefox start with that -profile setting, too?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really only one registry key for the default browser. There are many different keys for different file types and protocols, which means that achieving what you want can be difficult.

Here's a start for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. If you modify the default value to what you want it should open any link starting with `http://` or `https://` in Firefox with the wanted profile.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\https\shell\open\command
```